# Set selected color for image without removing reflections, shadows

Tags: android, colors, colormatrixfilter

I have image with one color(different shades) and alpha channel. Image has reflections and shadows. I want create RGB color and paint this image. I tried set ColorMatrixColorFilter, but this filter is applied to the the original color and creates a different color than was chosen.

```
filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new float[]
            {

                    1, 0, 0, 0, colors[0],
                    0, 1, 0, 0, colors[1],
                    0, 0, 1, 0, colors[2],
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0
            });
```

"colors" array has successively red, green, blue colors.

I also tried using this for images with grayscale, but this also not give me colour which i want.

When I set some value at 255, received color is unnatural without reflections and shadows.

Comment: maybe this will help http://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/colormatrix-guide

Comment: It didn't help me. Maybe I should calculate average color, then add in filter difference of these colors. It's a good idea?

Comment: i used CMCF only once or twice, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27990277/2252830